# Sending encrypted JSON with RSA from Spring to Android by REST

Tags: java, android, json, spring, encryption

Firstly sorry for my english ;]

I have to encrypt a JSON object with RSA encryption in WebService Spring, and send it by REST to android and decrypt it.

The problem is that after I've received in android an encrypted String, it is not the same like this which was sent from WebService.

**Sent encrypted String in WS:**
*cﾱ4ﾍ5Kﾉ[￰Z￹*

**Received encrypted String in Android:**
*ﾎﾳﾰￓ￴|￢ﾰﾓ}￙*

If decode it in android, I'm receiveng not the same data.

I was checking this by the same way only in WS. I've sent it from WS method by rest to another method in WS and everything works fine and I've received proper encrypted JSON ready to decode.

I checked encoding in both platforms, and both Spring and Android have the same UTF-8 encoding.

What may cause this problem?

**Encrypter/decrypter class in Spring:**

```
  private PrivateKey privateKey = null;
private PublicKey publicKey = null;

public RSA() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    final KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA"); // or "EC" or whatever
    final PrivateKey privateKey = kf.generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(RSA.byteArrPrivate));
    final PublicKey publicKey = kf.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(RSA.byteArrPublic));
    this.privateKey = privateKey;
    this.publicKey = publicKey;

}

public PrivateKey getPrivateKey() {
    return privateKey;
}

public void setPrivateKey(PrivateKey privateKey) {
    this.privateKey = privateKey;
}

public PublicKey getPublicKey() {
    return publicKey;
}

public void setPublicKey(PublicKey publicKey) {
    this.publicKey = publicKey;
}

public String byteToString(byte[] encrypted) {
    char[] cbuf = new char[encrypted.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < encrypted.length; i++) {
        cbuf[i] = (char) encrypted[i];
    }
    String encryptedString = new String(cbuf);
    return encryptedString;
}

public byte[] stringToByte(String encryptedString) {
    byte[] out = new byte[encryptedString.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < encryptedString.length(); i++) {
        out[i] = (byte) encryptedString.charAt(i);
    }
    return out;
}

public byte[] encrypt(String message, PublicKey pk) {
    Cipher cipher = null;
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pk);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    byte[] chiffrat = null;
    try {
        chiffrat = cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes());
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return chiffrat;
}

public String decrypt(byte[] chiffrat, PrivateKey sk) {
    byte[] dec = null;
    Cipher cipher = null;
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sk);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        dec = cipher.doFinal(chiffrat);
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new String(dec);
}
```

**Encrypting data in WS:**

```
                final Gson gson = new Gson();
            final String json = gson.toJson(price.body());
            final RSA rsa = new RSA();
            final byte[] encryptedArray = rsa.encrypt(json, rsa.getPublicKey());
            final String encryptedString = rsa.byteToString(encryptedArray);
            return JsonUtils.generateJsonResponse(encryptedString);
```

**Decrypter class in Android:**

```
  final private static String ENCRYPTION_METHOD_RSA = "RSA";
private PrivateKey privateKey = null;

public RSA() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    final KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(ENCRYPTION_METHOD_RSA);
    this.privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(RSA.BYTE_ARR_PRIVATE));
}

public PrivateKey getPrivateKey() {
    return privateKey;
}

public void setPrivateKey(PrivateKey privateKey) {
    this.privateKey = privateKey;
}

public String byteToString(byte[] encrypted) {
    final char[] cbuf = new char[encrypted.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < encrypted.length; i++) {
        cbuf[i] = (char) encrypted[i];
    }
    return new String(cbuf);
}

public byte[] stringToByte(String encryptedString) {
    final byte[] out = new byte[encryptedString.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < encryptedString.length(); i++) {
        out[i] = (byte) encryptedString.charAt(i);
    }
    return out;
}

public String decryptString(String encryptedString) {
    return decrypt(stringToByte(encryptedString), getPrivateKey());
}

public String decrypt(byte[] chiffrat, PrivateKey privateKey) {
    byte[] dec = null;
    Cipher cipher = null;
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ENCRYPTION_METHOD_RSA);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        if (cipher != null) {
            dec = cipher.doFinal(chiffrat);
        }
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dec == null ? "" : new String(dec);
}
```

**Decrypting in Android:**

```
    private void decryptString(INetworkCallback<ProductPriceModel> listener, String response) {
    String decryptedString = null;

    try {
        final RSA rsa = new RSA();

        decryptedString = rsa.decryptString(response);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (decryptedString == null || decryptedString.trim().isEmpty()) {
        listener.onFailure(CODE_FAIL, null);
    } else {
        final ProductPriceModel model = new Gson().fromJson(decryptedString, new TypeToken<ProductPriceModel>() {
        }.getType());
        listener.onSuccess(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you need to convert between bytes and strings use some encoding like Base64.

Comment: Thanks, response is now the same, but I have another problem. When I am decrypting an array only in WS it decrypts from 500length array to 4length array which is correct for my String. When I am decrypting it in Android, It decrypts from 500length array into 500length another array. What may cause the problem? The problem is in metod cipher.doFinal(); It works good in WS, bad in Android.